# PHP não exibe Json

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Tenho um um código que pega os dados de um formulário e envia para uma página PHP via AJAX.

Quando eu tento exibir os dados JSON, o PHP não exibe e só mostra colchetes como um vetor.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <title>Cadastro Cliente</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/popper-min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="js/envio.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="principal" class="container mt-5" left="10px">
        <form class="form-horizontal">
        <fieldset>

        <!-- Form Name -->
        <legend>Cadastro Cliente</legend>

        <!-- Text input-->
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="Digite o seu nome:">Nome:</label>  
          <div class="col-md-4">
          <input id="nome" name="Digite o seu nome:" type="text" placeholder="Digite seu nome" class="form-control input-md" required="true">
          <span class="help-block">nome</span>  
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Multiple Radios -->
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="Sexo">Sexo</label>
          <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="radio">
            <label for="Sexo-0">
              <input type="radio" name="sexo" id="sexo" value="M" checked="checked">
              Masculino
            </label>
            </div>
          <div class="radio">
            <label for="Sexo-1">
              <input type="radio" name="sexo" id="sexo" value="F">
              Feminino
            </label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Multiple Checkboxes (inline) -->
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="interesses">Interesses</label>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <label class="checkbox-inline" for="Interesses-0">
              <input type="checkbox" name="interesses[]" id="interesses" value="esportes">
              Esportes
            </label>
            <label class="checkbox-inline" for="Interesses-1">
              <input type="checkbox" name="interesses[]" id="interesses" value="estudar">
              Estudar
            </label>
            <label class="checkbox-inline" for="Interesses-2">
              <input type="checkbox" name="interesses[]" id="interesses" value="videogame">
              Video Game
            </label>
            <label class="checkbox-inline" for="Interesses-3">
              <input type="checkbox" name="interesses[]" id="interesses" value="outros">
              Outros
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Select Basic -->
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="como">Como nos encontrou ?</label>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <select id="como" name="como" class="form-control">
              <option value="" selected>Escolher</option>
              <option value="Tv">Tv</option>
              <option value="amigos">Amigos</option>
              <option value="familia">Família</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Textarea -->
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="comentarios">Comentários</label>
          <div class="col-md-4">                     
            <textarea class="form-control" id="comentarios" name="comentarios">Comente Aqui !!!</textarea>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Button (Double) -->
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="enviar">Enviar</label>
          <div class="col-md-8">
            <button type="submit" id="enviar" name="enviar" class="btn btn-success">Enviar</button>
            <button type="reset" id="reset" name="reset" class="btn btn-danger">Resetar</button>
          </div>
        </div>

        </fieldset>
        </form>
        <span id="resp"></span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript/Jquery (Esse é o envio.js):

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('form').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    })

    $("#enviar").click(function(){
        let cliente = {};

        cliente.nome = $("#nome").val(); // pega o nome do cliente
        cliente.sexo= $("#sexo:checked").val();// pega o sexo selecionado
        cliente.comentarios = $("#comentarios").val();// armazena os comentários
        cliente.como = $("#como").val();// armazena o valor do select

        let interesses = new Array();

        $.each($("#interesses:checked"),function(indice,elemento){
            interesses[indice] = elemento.value;
        })

        cliente.interesses = interesses;

        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'php/destino.php',
            context:document.body,
            data:cliente,
            dataType:'json',
            success:function(resposta){
                console.log(resposta);
                $("#resp").attr('style','color:blue');
                $("#resp").html(resposta.nome +" "+ "Cadastro feito com sucesso !!");
            },
            error:function(erro){
                console.log(erro);
                $("#resp").attr('style','color:red');
                $("#resp").html(erro);
            }
        })
    })
})
```

PHP (destino.php):

```
<?php  
    echo json_encode($_POST);
?>
```

Comment: Será que este erro não está acontecendo porque você está definindo o Content-Type como `json`, sendo que este MIME type não existe? Tente redefini-lo como `application/json`. Na verdade na maioria das vezes você não precisa defini-lo manualmente, o jQuery faz isso para você.

Answer (score 0):

Utilize o método [`serialize`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) para pegar os dados do formulário, assim não é necessário pegar os dados do cliente no Javascript manualmente.

```
$("#enviar").click(function(){

     $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'php/destino.php',
        context:document.body,
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        dataType:'json',
        success:function(resposta){
            console.log(resposta);
            $("#resp").attr('style','color:blue');
            $("#resp").html(resposta.responseJSON.nome + " Cadastro feito com sucesso !!");
        },
        error:function(erro){
            console.log(erro);
            $("#resp").attr('style','color:red');
            $("#resp").html(erro);
        }
    });

});
```

Código no PHP:

```
<?php

$nomeCliente = $_POST['nome'];

echo json_encode([
    'nome' => $nomeCliente,
    // Outros dados podem ser adicionados no array se precisar
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Isso é porque você está usando a versão do jQuery Slim. Substitua pela versão jQuery Uncompressed abaixo, que irá funcionar(baixe e cole em sua pasta js que é o seu contexto, site para download é este [aqui](https://code.jquery.com/)):

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Pois o [jQuery Slim](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.js) não possui a função $.ajax o [jQuery Uncompressed](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js) sim, inclusive quando você depura vai aparecer a mensagem informando que  **$ajax is not a function**.
Aproveite ainda e coloque os outros campos do formulário. Segue alterações que fiz para melhoria:

Arquivo index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <title>Cadastro Cliente</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function ()
            {
                $('form').submit(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                })

                $("#enviar").click(function () {
                    let cliente = {};

                    cliente.nome = $("#nome").val(); // pega o nome do cliente
                    cliente.sexo = $("#sexo:checked").val();// pega o sexo selecionado
                    cliente.comentarios = $("#comentarios").val();// armazena os comentários
                    cliente.como = $("#como").val();// armazena o valor do select

                    let interesses = new Array();

                    $.each($("#interesses:checked"), function (indice, elemento) {
                        interesses[indice] = elemento.value;
                    })

                    cliente.interesses = interesses;

                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'php/destino.php',
                        context: document.body,
                        data: cliente,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function (resposta) {
                            console.log(resposta);
                            $("#resp").attr('style', 'color:blue');
                            $("#resp").html("<h6>Cadastro feito com sucesso !!!</h6>Dados preenchidos:<div style='color:black'>" + "Nome: " + resposta.nome + "<br>Sexo: " + resposta.sexo + "<br>Interesses: " + resposta.interesses + "<br>Comentários: " + resposta.comentarios + "</div>");
                        },
                        error: function (erro) {
                            console.log(erro);
                            $("#resp").attr('style', 'color:red');
                            $("#resp").html(erro);
                        }
                    })
                })
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="principal" class="container mt-5" style="left: 10px;">
            <form class="form-horizontal">
                <fieldset>

                    <!-- Form Name -->
                    <legend>Cadastro Cliente</legend>

                    <!-- Text input-->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="Digite o seu nome:">Nome:</label>  
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <input id="nome" name="Digite o seu nome:" type="text" placeholder="Digite seu nome" class="form-control input-md" required="true">
                            <span class="help-block">nome</span>  
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Multiple Radios -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="Sexo">Sexo</label>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="radio">
                                <label for="Sexo-0">
                                    <input type="radio" name="sexo" id="sexo" value="M" checked="checked">
                                    Masculino
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="radio">
                                <label for="Sexo-1">
                                    <input type="radio" name="sexo" id="sexo" value="F">
                                    Feminino
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Multiple Checkboxes (inline) -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="interesses">Interesses</label>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <label class="checkbox-inline" for="Interesses-0">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="interesses[]" id="interesses" value="esportes">
                                Esportes
                            </label>
                            <label class="checkbox-inline" for="Interesses-1">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="interesses[]" id="interesses" value="estudar">
                                Estudar
                            </label>
                            <label class="checkbox-inline" for="Interesses-2">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="interesses[]" id="interesses" value="videogame">
                                Video Game
                            </label>
                            <label class="checkbox-inline" for="Interesses-3">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="interesses[]" id="interesses" value="outros">
                                Outros
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Select Basic -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="como">Como nos encontrou ?</label>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <select id="como" name="como" class="form-control">
                                <option value="" selected>Escolher</option>
                                <option value="Tv">Tv</option>
                                <option value="amigos">Amigos</option>
                                <option value="familia">Família</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Textarea -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="comentarios">Comentários</label>
                        <div class="col-md-4">                     
                            <textarea class="form-control" id="comentarios" name="comentarios">Comente Aqui !!!</textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Button (Double) -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="enviar">Enviar</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <button type="submit" id="enviar" name="enviar" class="btn btn-success">Enviar</button>
                            <button type="reset" id="reset" name="reset" class="btn btn-danger">Resetar</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </fieldset>
            </form>

            <span id="resp"></span>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

destino.php

```
<?php

echo json_encode($_POST);
```